# Angular 8 set selected value in dropdown based on string

Tags: angular, angular8

I have this code:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="pricingTemplateId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Margin</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer">
                {{customer.pricingTemplateName}}
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="PricingTemplatesList">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Margin Template</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer">
                <select id="pricingtemplates" name="ddlPricingTemplate">
                    <option *ngFor="let pricingTemplate of customer.pricingTemplatesList" [(ngModel)]="customer.pricingTemplateName">{{pricingTemplate.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

For the select control I'm attaching array of objects like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Now, I also have another string value in the model on which I want to base the selected value in the dropdown.

When I do `[(ngModel)]="customer.pricingTemplateName"` which is basically a string I'm getting this message "No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"

Without the ngModel property I'm able to list all the template names in the dropdown but do I need to do some change in order to set the selected value based on a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing 2 way data binding with `[(ngModel)]` on the `<option>` for a start. This would need to go on the `<select>` And then you can set the `[value]="pricingTemplate.name"` of option within the ngFor loop and this will get picked up by the select element.

```
<select id="pricingtemplates" name="ddlPricingTemplate" [(ngModel)]="customer.pricingTemplateName">
   <option *ngFor="let pricingTemplate of customer.pricingTemplatesList" [value]="pricingTemplate.name">
     {{pricingTemplate.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam but I'm still getting this error "No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"

Comment: This is what I did in the option line: <option *ngFor="let pricingTemplate of customer.pricingTemplatesList" [(ngModel)]="customer.pricingTemplateName" value="customer.pricingTemplateName">{{pricingTemplate.name}}</option>

Comment: I have provided an example of what i mean.

Comment: Thanks, that works, the only thing you were missing were the double brackets which I added for the [value] in the option control. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `compareWith`
check the link
https://netbasal.com/understanding-the-comparefn-input-in-angular-v4-4a401ef4fc4c